# How to catch this error : " line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed"?

Tags: java, salesforce, automated-tests, apex

I am writing a Java application that run test automatically on salesForce account and display the result in a excel document.

But I have a probleme :
One of my classe doesnt compile, so I obtain this error :

```
line 49, column 35: Invalid type: FooClass
```

And the problem is after that all my classes test fail with this error :

```
line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: APB005_AudienceMember_Update_TEST: line 49, column 35: Invalid type: APB005_AudienceMember_Update.
```

This is the part of code that execute all tests on salesforce platform :

```
    connector = new SoapConnection(config);
    RunTestsRequest request = new RunTestsRequest();
    request.setAllTests(true);

    //execution of All tests
    RunTestsResult r = connector.runTests(request);
```

Is there anyway to continue the tests even if a compilation error appears?

Comment: That's... a new one. Are you loading classes with a ClassLoader?

Comment: No .. at all 
I configure just my request to run all test (request.setAllTests(true)  ) using salesForce API, after that I dont know how it works inside